# Unable to get the bitmap of a linearlayout along with its child views

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I am creating the bitmap from a linearlayout with the following code

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v ) {

```
    //Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams.width, v.getLayoutParams.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams.width, v.getLayoutParams.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

but i can not see the views in it 
all i can see is a big grey screen

have tried the answer at this question also [Android Problems Converting ViewGroup with Children into Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960753/android-problems-converting-viewgroup-with-children-into-bitmap) but still not working

My view is being inflated from xml 
and when i use the code mentioned above i get force close for null pointer exception
and if i mention the width and height to some number like 200 , 200 then i am able to see the grey background only not the view in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to measure the view before layout like

```
v.measure(
      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().width,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
      MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight()
        ,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.draw(c);
```

Comment: m getting a nullpointer exception on MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(v.getLayoutParams().width,MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)

Comment: well you'll need to find which variable is bull. most probably 'v' will be null.

Comment: the problem was that i wasnt mentioning the width and height of the linearlayout in java but in xml now it is working thanks a lot